# How to use unencrypted SMTP/POP3 to connect to Outlook.com, Gmail or other email services?

Tags: smtp, pop3

My new multifunction printer only works with unencrypted SMTP and POP3 (so 90's!), but most of the popular email services such as Outlook.com and Gmail only support encrypted SMTP and POP3. Is there a way to enable the printer to talk to those email services?

I'm trying to avoid setting up an intermediate computer (either acting as a mail server or tunneling SMTP/POP3 to Gmail).

Comment: What do you expect?  If you are unwilling to tunnel through another service, and you can't upgrade the printer, and you can't get your service to allow unencrypted connections, then there's nothing left that can be done.

Comment: My original question was asking for services that offer unencrypted SMTP/POP, but it was removed (I assume it wasn't allowed to ask for specific product/service here).

Comment: There is stunnel but that aside. Your phrasing near the end, makes no sense. What does tunneling SMTP/POP3 to Gmail mean?!  Tunneling is encapsulating one protocol within another. Gmail is a product. You tunnel a connection within a connection, you don't tunnel a protocol to a product. What on earth do you mean?! Tunneling is  a technical term, don't use the term so loosely and meaninglessly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out unencrypted SMTP access is supported: https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600?hl=en#

Answer (score 1):

Unless there is a firmware update, these MFPs (Multifunction Printers) will not scan to email through these services. Encryption is there for your protection, and to help better the Internet, believe it or not.

As for the actual issue? I would ask if you could use your company's email server, or your ISP's mail servers. I have the same issue with a Lexmark printer, and I figured it out *for* their tech support that Gmail requires encryption - I used Telnet to get the actual error sorted out.

My ISP (Shaw) supports encryption, but allows users to send unencrypted emails as well. I pointed the SMTP server to Shaw's, and the emails started coming in again. Short of that, running your own mail server would be the next-best situation, but I believe that would be out of the scope of this question.

Answer (score 0):

Google offers a free service for printers to email.

Enter this for your outgoing SMTP server address
aspmx.l.google.com

No username, and no password...It will fail if you enter one....

http://cavewall.jaguardesignstudio.com/2011/10/12/google-apps-smtp-without-ssl-part-1/